# Deprecating Warnings in Open-Sourced Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, deprecated

I'm currently updating a library, and for users with iOS 7.0 and above, a certain method is deprecated.

I've implemented the following logic to use the correct methods:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
    //Use old deprecated method 
} else {
    //Use the new method supported in 7.0
}
```

If I use the following in my if statement to silence the warning, and users ship this code in their apps will their apps be rejected or will it be okay?

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
//old deprecated method 
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: I silenced warnings in third party libs in the past, and it never was a problem, as long as the app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, until Apple removes support for an API, they will not reject it usage in an app.

---

Be careful modifying third party libraries. There are legal implications for modifying open source depending on the license.

Whenever possible, I modify the build system that compiles the third party code. For example, if I have the source files directly included in my project, then I will suppress the needed warnings for just those files.

- Select the project node in the *Project Navigator*.
- Select the *Build Phases* header.
- Expand the *Compile Sources* section.
- Set `-Wdeprecated-declarations` in *Compiler Flags* for the open source files.